# How to Keep Specific Data in ExcelSheet

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Hi I have one Excel sheet and version is 2010. In that Excel sheet there is Many column but one of column is Branch which contains Branch Name like AAA, BBB, CCC..etc. Now i want to keep data of only AAA Branch and data of another branch will delete. How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Autofilter on your data table. Filter to show only branch "AAA"

Select the table, hit F5 > Special > tick Visible cells > OK > hit Ctrl-C to copy

Create a new sheet and paste.

Now you will see only the data with branch "AAA" in the new sheet.

This is basic Excel functionality and really does not have a place in SO, where questions are about code. Questions about basic out of the box functionality of software should be posted at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)